# How can I scale down my Azure Redis cache from standard to basic?

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to scale down my Redis cache on Azure but get error saying that "Standard plan cannot be changed to Basic."

Someone knows a way to change this without creating a new Redis cache?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it now. [Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-scale/)

"You can't scale from a Standard cache to a Basic cache."

That was asked before on the [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache/suggestions/6358526-it-should-be-possible-to-scale-up-pricing-plan-for) but it looks like there is no possibility to do that yet. So, the only way is to create the new one.

Comment: There's another suggestion on UserVoice for scaling to different plans: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache/suggestions/13793043-scale-to-basic